# How do I modify is_front_page()?

Tags: wordpress

I'm not quiet understanding this function but all I want is the homepage to say the name of the company and then on other pages it should say page title | company name. This all works with the below code EXCEPT for the pipe.

```
<?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title('');
    ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

What I don't understand is where to put the pipe and anything I append to the is_front_page() function crashes the site.

FYI, to hide the home page header from being shown I do have a plugin installed called Hide Title.

http://www.centurygloveandsafety.com

Comment: Looking at the documentation (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) It looks like you have to specify the pipe as an argument to `wp_title` but you just have an empty string (`''`). Replace it with the pipe that you want (`' | '`)

Comment: BTW, you don't *modify* the `is_front_page` function. It doesn't make sense to modify it. And I don't understand what you mean by appending to it. It returns a boolean value that determines if you are at the front page. It's not something that you should append something to.

Comment: @KodosJohnson, append was a poor choice of words - modify would have more accurate. And I had tried just adding the pipe as you suggested but that moved the pipe to the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also write the code like this (same meaning):

```
if(is_front_page()) {
   bloginfo('description'); // echo blog description
} else {
   wp_title(''); // echo wp_title (see WordPress Codex)
}
bloginfo('name'); // echo name of blog
```

However you say you want the *homepage* to say the *name of the company* and on *other pages* it should say *title | company name*. Do the following:

```
if(is_front_page()) {
   bloginfo('name');
} else {
   wp_title('');
   echo " | ";
   bloginfo('name');
}
```

Comment: Yes, the if statement was the way to go. I don't know why I didn't think about that.

Comment: Maybe you were confused by the "ternary operator". For more information just google it.